# problem with hebrew in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hebrew

i want to change the  SearchForm.php file in my wordpress themes to hebrew.
i mean i want to see 'חפש' (hebrew text) instead of 'search for '.

when i change it i see gebrish.

why ??

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the content-type of the page is the correct one - normally UTF-8 would work for all languages.

You can use a meta tag within the `head` element:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

For Hebrew it is iso-8859-8.

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-8">
```

This is normally already setup within the template and you can look at your settings to see if it is correct - In Settings -> Reading, under "Encoding for pages and feeds".

You also need to be sure that the page is saved as UTF-8 and not ascii - check your text editor settings.

Comment: ok, i check that and is on UTF-8

what is the name of the file, i need to put the meta tag ?
thanks.

Comment: @ROI - if it is UTF-8, check in the source (view source in browser) that it is correctly there. Then check that the file that you updated is also saved in UTF-8.

Comment: i check it, everything is ok with the encode 
I try to put the meta line belongs to the subject in header.php
but i still see gebrish.

Comment: @ROI - what do you see when you look at the page source in the browser? Are you sure the browser is using the correct encoding (in FF it is under View -> Character Encoding)?

Comment: link to my website with the problem 
and you cn to enter to view soucre and see that the encoding is on utf-8

link:
www.104u.co.il/blog2

Comment: @ROI - I am unable to access that site at all. Can you paste the relevant bits in your question?