# register usernames in wordpress in hebrew

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I would like to be able for visitors in my website to register with a Hebrew username.

In my website when I try to register with a Hebrew character username it gives me no error,
the user receives an email saying he was successfully registered and the admin gets an email with the user's details,

BUT

The user does not actually register to the database... he does not show in the users table and when he tries to log-in there is an error saying there is no such user...

This does not happen with English usernames

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this is the same issue with your's? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391484/problem-with-hebrew-in-wordpress

Comment: i dont think so because its not showing gibrish charecters its not showing anything at all... and all my site is in hebrew and it shows all charecters just fine... i have been searching for 3 days now for a solution for this and i havent even found someone with the same problem as i have...

Comment: Then, perhaps it's the problem with your MySQL Database (assuming you have MySQL). Have you tried changing the db_charset for your database?

Comment: yes, but i don't know if i have done it right...

Comment: could you be more detailed?

Comment: see my answer. perhaps that helps

Answer (score 1):

**Short description of the problem:** (and possible solution)

when wordpress creates the user's nicename ("A string that contains a URL-friendly name for the user").

If you specified a Hebrew username this will be a list of html entities.
In my test, the Hebrew username was "בדיקהקהקהק" with a sanitized username of "%d7%91%d7%93%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94%d7%a7%d7%94%d7%a7%d7%a7" (54 characters).

The lenght of field user_nicename is 50 characters in the wordpress database. (this explains by the way, why it worked with usernames up to 8 characters)

Taking a look at the Wordpress code of user.php, we can see that Wordpress is checking the length of `user_nicename` before inserting the user, but it doesn't work.

Let me show you why:
the code to check `user_nicename` length is something like this:

```
$user_nicename = sanitize_user( $userdata['user_nicename'], true );
    if ( mb_strlen( $user_nicename ) > 50 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'user_nicename_too_long', __( 'Nicename may not be longer than 50 characters.' ) );
    }
```

When using a Hebrew username, regardless of the length of the generated `user_nicename`, the condition will always be true because the function `sanitize_user()` "removes all unsafe characters" - including html entities, and returns an empty string, length = 0.

Eventually passing the check you could have the impression that the user was created without error, but it wasn't because of the data exceeding the field length in `user_nicename`.

Possible solutions are to programmatically cut the string to 50 characters, forcing some stacig `user_nicename` like "user-1", "user-2" etc, or using latin characters for `user_nicename` either with [PHP Transliterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) or a custom library/function.

I picked the last solution and because I used shared hosting without an option to install additional libraries.

**Working code**
inserted into function.php of my template:

```
// user creation with Hebrew usernames

//function to transliterate username
function convert_user_nicename($hebrew_username) {
    $charset = array('א'=>'a','ב'=>'b','ג'=>'g','ד'=>'d','ה'=>'h','ו'=>'v','ז'=>'z','ח'=>'h','ט'=>'t','י'=>'y','ך'=>'k','כ'=>'k','ל'=>'l','ם'=>'m','מ'=>'m','ן'=>'n','נ'=>'n','ס'=>'s','ע'=>'e','ף'=>'p','פ'=>'p','ץ'=>'ts','צ'=>'ts','ק'=>'q','ר'=>'r','ש'=>'sh','ת'=>'t');
    $latin_user_slug = '';
    $chars = mbStringToArray($hebrew_username);
    foreach ($chars as $key =>$char) {
        $latin_user_slug .= $charset[$char];
    }
    return($latin_user_slug);    
}
function mbStringToArray ($string) { 
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string); 
    while ($strlen) { 
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8"); 
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8"); 
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string); 
    } 
    return $array; 
} 

// remove the filter 
remove_filter( 'pre_user_nicename', 'filter_pre_user_nicename', 10, 1 ); 
function filter_pre_user_nicename($user_nicename) { 
    $heb = html_entity_decode($user_nicename);
    $user_nicename = convert_user_nicename($heb); 
    return $user_nicename; 
}; 

// add new filter 
add_filter( 'pre_user_nicename', 'filter_pre_user_nicename', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the MySQL Server connection collation. If you have PhpMyAdmin, you can simply change this by logging in to PhpMyAdmin. And then, on the front page you will see the  Server connection collation (on the General tab).

Change the server connection collation into hebrew_general_ci to support Hebrew based texts in the database.

[image]

References:

https://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/change-database-collation/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: do i need to change this option as well in the the wp-config.php file? the line -----
/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', ''); 
----
it says don't change if in doubt and I'm kind on in a doubt what do you think?

Comment: i tried what you said and still no luck... i even went in to the database and changed the Collation in the wp-users table to the user-login field to the hebrew_general_ci and still no luck.